# Как отправить картинку в джанго

Tags: django

В проекте пользователь заполняет форму, одно из полей которой - загружаемая картинка. Успешно создается объект в БД, данные должны отправляться на почту админу, но метод send_mail() принимает в качестве сообщения только строки

Comment: у  `send_mail()` есть параметр `html_message`. Туда передайте `render_to_string('path/to/your/htm_file.html')`  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/#send-mail

Comment: html_message = render_to_string('letter_request_card.html', {
                'user': user,
                'email': email,
                'user_card': user_card,
                'form': form,
            }) и он подхватывает все, кроме картинки. как ее правильно обернуть?

Answer (score 0):

Картинку просто передайте в `render_to_string`

```
html_message = render_to_string('letter_request_card.html', { 'user': user, 'email': email, 'user_card': user_card, 'form': form, 'img':your_img })
```